# using statement with ExecuteReader() seems to cause performance hit

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance

In my code, which streams data from a stored procedure in SQL Server into a `.csv` file, I had this:

```
...
using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    ...
}
```

The code was running very slowly.

I got rid of the using directive to the following:

```
...
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
...
```

Now it runs a lot more quickly. What is the reason for this performance difference?

The code is firing a relatively simple SQL script in a stored procedure that returns 2 million rows of data which is 3 columns wide.

Comment: A using _statement_ is different from a using _directive_

Comment: @maccettura in my question which is it - a statement or directive? (it depends?) ...feel free to edit the question

Comment: This question can´t be solved. You have to use a profiler to determine what takes how much time in your program. Anyway *very slow* and *more quickly* are quite subjective, you need some real measurement. Otherwise it´s likely that you hunt for a dead man.

Comment: @HimBromBeere in theory should they perform the same?

Comment: @whytheq your question describes a using *statement*.  A using directive is what imports namespaces (i.e `using System.Linq;`)

Comment: No, of course not, as `using` will automatically call `Dispose` when leaving the code-block which of course takes some time. In particular it may lead to the gabage-collector kicking in. However you should *not* omit the `using`-statement just because your app runs slower.

Comment: Yes, there shouldn't be any significant difference.

Comment: @Blorgbeard that is what I imagined as the using statement is just for garbage collection

Comment: That´s not entirely true, the `using` will call `Dispose` which is used to release *unmanaged* ressources that can´t be garbage-collected.

Comment: Can you profile the difference? I don't tend to trust people's gut feelings when it comes to performance.

Comment: OP, try profiling the SQL and check for logical reads vs. physical reads. If the physical reads are low, it probably means the data were already cached in memory, which can happen the second time you run a query.

Comment: According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.close(v=vs.110).aspx: "The Close method fills in the values for output parameters, return values and RecordsAffected, increasing the time that it takes to close a SqlDataReader that was used to process a large or complex query." I would say 2 million rows would fall into the large query category. The link provided also says calling Cancel before calling Close can reduce this time. Behind the scenes I believe using calls Dispose() (which is what Close calls I think).

Comment: @MikeCheel interesting that in the code example on the page you linked to they do not have `using` for the reader - I think none of the msdn examples I've seen have a `using` for a reader

Comment: I've seen somewhere that Close (not sure if it is data reader or not) wraps Dispose and so wrapping in a using would be tantamount to calling dispose twice. If I am right that is probably why. I'm guessing it calls Dispose after filling in the out parameters, return values and records affected.

Comment: Please supply an MVCE

Comment: @MartinSmith "MVCE" ?

Comment: Or MCVE! Example code that we can run that reproduces the issue.

Comment: ahhh MCVE: minimal, complete and verifiable example ... I will try to add next week (if the question is not closed by then..)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It could be that the second time you ran it,  the database had already cached the data in memory.

Answer (score 3):

The **using** closes and disposes the reader, thats why it is a bit slower (some milliseconds).
If the garbagecollector kicks in while your code is executing you will have an impact.

But there is no reason to omit this using. 
When profiling your code, you will recognize, that there won't be a big impact on the performance, caused by the using.

Thanks to [Mike Cheel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/426422/mike-cheel):

"The Close method fills in the values for output parameters, return values and RecordsAffected, increasing the time that it takes to close a SqlDataReader that was used to process a large or complex query. When the return values and the number of records affected by a query are not significant, the time that it takes to close the SqlDataReader can be reduced by calling the Cancel method of the associated SqlCommand object before calling the Close method."

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.close(v=vs.110).aspx

So my interpretation is, that it causes an performance impact when having a large query like 2million rows.

**Edit**:

So i was wrong when i was thinking it would only cost milliseconds, it seems that the using definetly can have a bigger impact on the overall performance on such large queries.

Comment: It has nothing to do with performance. And it is done after the operation has ended!!

Comment: The time taken to close the reader is not going to be perceptible to a human in the normal case.

Comment: Well it is not clearly specified, how he measured the execution time. There should not be a big difference, except that the using causes the reader to be closed after the statements are executed. So the using causes the code to run a few milliseconds slower.

Comment: I don't think that the difference between "very slowly" and "a lot more quickly" is measured in milliseconds to any reasonable person.

Comment: Generally speaking, it has no impact on the performance.

Comment: It has if you do it a thousand times. Plus if the gc kicks in it will definetly have an impact. But still there is no reason to omit the using

Comment: So msdn proves you guys wrong, or do i interpret that piece of information wrong?

Comment: @TobiasTheel are there examples on msdn when a reader is used with `using` ?

Comment: I haven't found one yet. It looks like they are allways calling the Close method themselves.